# Sharepoint online site not opening in SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Im using SharePoint designer and when i try to open my online site in designer im getting the below error message, should i enable any settings?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You note that you are using SharePoint Online, if so the follow possibilities may be blocking SharePoint Designer access:

- If you are attempting to open the root site collection (e.g. https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/), the root site collection in SharePoint Online does not allow SharePoint Designer access.
- If you are attempting to open one of the other site collections (e.g. https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/someothersite), Go to that site's "Site Settings" Page (e.g. https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/someothersite/_layouts/15/settings.aspx), and under the subheading "Site Collection Administration", click "SharePoint Designer Settings", and verify that SharePoint Designer access is allowed on this site.
- Note that if this is a Modern-mode site, the "SharePoint Designer Settings" will not be available, but Designer access is NOT blocked on Modern sites.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot, not able to upvote your answer because of less reputations.

Answer (score 0):

Your site does not open in SharePoint designer. The error is as above.

One possible reason is that this site has Designer disabled (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940958)

Another cause (less likely to guess) is that this site was created using a template saved from a site where Designer was disabled.

RESOLUTION:

- One straight forward way of doing it is from the UI (Which did not work in my case though :(  )

  1. Right-click the ONET.XML file ( at \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\\xml) for the site definition and open it with Notepad

     If you see “DisableWebDesignFeatures=wdfopensite” section in the one.xml that means your site has been configured to disallow SharePoint designer.

     You can remove this section from the file and should be able to access the site in designer now
  2. If you are unable to get rid of “DisableWebDesignFeatures=wdfopensite” or find the correct onet.xml corresponding to your site definition, here is a simple script I put together to see if Designer is disabled on the site using the property vti_disablewebdesignfeatures2 and update it as required.

for information refer this link,

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/namkh/the-web-site-has-been-configured-to-disallow-editing-with-sharepoint-designer

Comment: His question was tagged as #sharepoint-online.  What you propose is only possible in an on-prem environment.